# Rails 4 ExecJS::ProgramError in Listings#index

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

After adding JavaScript to my web app I now get the following errors:

```
ExecJS::ProgramError in Listings#index

[stdin]:16:5: error: unexpected else
    else
    ^^^^
  (in /Users/Desktop/Rails/foodapp/app/assets/javascripts/orders.js.coffee)
```

application.html.etb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Foodapp</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "https://js.stripe.com/v2/" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <%= tag :meta, :name => "stripe-key", :content => ENV["STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY"] %>
</head>
<body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
       <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
            <% if msg.is_a?(String) %>
                   <div class="alert alert-<%= name == :notice ? "success" : "danger" %> alert-dismissable">
                             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

orders.js.cofee

```
jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  payment.setupForm()

payment =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#new_order').submit ->
        $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
        Stripe.card.createToken($('#new_order'), payment.handleStripeResponse)
        false

  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 200
      $('#new_order').append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(response.id))
      $('#new_order')[0].submit()
    else
      $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message).show()
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false)
```

listing.index.html.erb

```
<h2>All products</h2>

<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="center">Name</th>
      <th class="center">Description</th>
      <th class="center">Stock</th>
      <th class="center">Price</th>
      <th class="center">Sold by</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @listings.each do |listing| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= listing.name %></td>
        <td><%= listing.description %></td>
        <td><%= listing.stock %></td>
        <td><%= number_to_currency(listing.price) %></td>
        <td><%= listing.user.name %></td>
        <%= link_to 'Buy Now', listing, class: "btn btn-link" %>

      </tr>

    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<% if user_signed_in? %>
<%= link_to 'New Listing', new_listing_path, class: "btn btn-link" %>
<% end %>
```

listings.show

```
<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @listing.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @listing.description %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Stock:</strong>
  <%= @listing.stock %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Price:</strong>
  <%= number_to_currency(@listing.price) %>
</p>

<%= link_to "Buy It Now", new_listing_order_path(@listing), class: "btn btn-primary", data: { no_turbolink: true } %>

<% if current_user == @listing.user %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_listing_path(@listing), class: "btn btn-link" %> |
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', listings_path, class: "btn btn-link" %>
```

gemfile

source 'https://rubygems.org'
source 'https://code.stripe.com'

```
ruby "2.0.0"
gem 'rails', '4.0.4'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'devise'
gem "figaro"
gem 'stripe'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

Comment: It is very strange bug. When is paste your code I didn't get any errors. In such situation I usually delete probably erroing peaces of code, and try to find a bug;)

Comment: yes did that i thought it might be the turbolinks code added after the buy button

Comment: this type of error mean that coffeescript preprocessor can't compile your coffee to js and it means that error is in your coffee code. I'm sure that error doesn't raise because of your data attributes at the buy button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have encountered the same issue.
I guess the error is caused by a text indention of the line with number 16.

I am using Sublime 3 editor.
My solution was a pretty much simple:
  1. Change `tab with = 2` property at right and bottom side of editor window.
  2. Select `Convert Indentation to Spaces` at the same side.